# TinyMCE Custom Elements with a ' : '?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, thymeleaf, angular-ui-tinymce

So I'm looking to allow Thymeleaf tags inside my TinyMce Editor (using angular-ui-tinymce if that matters)

I understand the basic format

```
 extended_valid_elements : 'script[charset|language|type|src]'
```

but how would I use this to allow for things like

```
 <p th:text="..."> //or// <img th:src="..."/>
```

Before anyone asks, yes it is necessary to have both tinyMce and thymeleaf, and No I don't need the thymeleaf to work inside tinymce, I just need the editor to stop stripping the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your TinyMCE configuration:

```
valid_elements: "*[*]"
```

Comment: I realize I worded the question incorrectly, the th:text and such are attributes not elements. using "*[*]" does not work in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
extended_valid_elements : 'img[th::text]'
```

Double colon symbol works as a single ':' char, but unfortunately you can't add attribute to * (any element) in extended_valid_elements. But you can list all needed elements.